# Gatsby cloud removing netlify functions from Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-function

I have netlify functions setup in my gatsby project with proxying and so forth. If i deploy through netlify everything works as expected. If I do another deploy with [gatsby cloud](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/cloud/) it actually removes my netlify functions from netlify.

I have tried setting up the functions through the netlify UI and with a toml. It all works if I deploy through Netlify, but when I do a deploy with gatsby cloud the netlify-functions disappears again.

Not sure if code is relevant here – but let me know and I'll share.

### Steps to reproduce

- Setup gatsby project with `gatsby-plugin-netlify-functions`
- [Follow these instructions](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-12-17-turning-the-static-dynamic/)
- Add site to Netlify and deploy
- Check if functions are working
- Add site to gatsby cloud
- Add netlify deploy integration
- Deploy to netlify
- See if functions are working or if they have disappeared

Comment: I've been asking around in the discord gatsby community – but no luck yet

Comment: Hi Mike, I work on the Gatsby Cloud team. I can reproduce this. Would you be able to email this post along with the link to your Gatsby Cloud site to support@gatsbyjs.com? We can start tracking this and better keep you updated that way.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now available on Gatsby Cloud.

For now how we are handling this is that we will deploy any functions found in `/public/functions` after `gatsby build`.

If you are still using the `gatsby-plugin-netlify-functions` plugin, setting the `functionsOutput` setting to `${__dirname}/public/functions` should get your functions deployed.

If not, you can you hook into `onPostBuild` in `gatsby-node.js` and copy the files there. (That's what `gatsby-plugin-netlify-functions` is doing behind the scenes!)

Comment: Is this still the case? according to https://joshwcomeau.com/gatsby/netlify-functions-and-gatsby-cloud/ they should be getting deployed from `/functions` - though I'm not entirely sure if this will work with un-bundled functions - it doesn't appear to work at all for  me at least.

Comment: @GuyBowden `/functions` does not work, but `/static/functions` does.